# How to display HTML table inside label binding based on checkboxlist binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a beginner in asp.net. I want to display an HTML table inside a label and check box list; for example, I have 2 columns in the table like **`Team Name` & `Team Member`**

I have 2 tables in the database like `Team Name` and `Team Member`.
The `Team Name` table contains values like Team A, Team B, Team C, etc. 
The `Team Member` table contains names like aa, bb, cc, etc. for each team name. If I run that aspx page it means the `Team Name` and `Team Member` will be displayed based on the database. The `Team Member` details like checkboxlist and `Team Name` like Label. How do I bind the check box list with the html table ?
Please help me.

I want to bind label with html table Column Team Name.*

```
Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sample").ConnectionString
Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
Dim CmdString As String = "TeamBindingProc "
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdString, con)
data.SelectCommand = cmd
data.Fill(ds)
Session("TeamId") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TeamId")
con.Open()
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    Dim table1 As New Table
    Dim tr As New TableRow
    Dim td3 As New TableCell
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Text = reader.Item("TeamName").ToString()
    td3.Controls.Add(lbl)
    tr.Cells.Add(td3)
    table1.Controls.Add(tr)
End While
con.Close()

End Sub
```

This code is for TeamName binding, but I don't know how to bind the checkbox list based on the TeamName. For example, Team A having aa, bb, cc and team B Having ee, yy, rr and team c having ii, ss, ww, rr. I want to display those names in the check box list.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot bind label with html code.Use Literal control which allows you to do the same.

Checkbox list can have checkboxname and checkbox , there cannot be two columns.

better option might be to use gridview with first column as checkbox.

Comment: my boss said don't use grid view already i did that Same concept using List view I got the Output,how to use literal control?can u help me...

Comment: literal is similar to label, u need to assign it html text and it will render it as expected by parsing html tags.

Comment: ok sir thanks For Your reply.. How to bind check box list BAsed on that Label?